# Dimplejs can deal with array of objects in each Json Object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, dimple.js

I'm trying to create vis with array of objects and in each object there is another array of objects.

```
 dataTest.push({"userId":
                            d["userId"], "LevAvg":
                            d["LevAvg"], "Changes":
                            [{ "Day": formattedDate, "Lev": d["Lev"], "Class": d["Class"], 
"ActiveLocation": d["ActiveLocation"] }]                        
});
```

i can create vis in X axis userId Y axis is days and each of the values in the array of user is bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid dimple doesn't work with nested arrays or objects, you would need to flatten the json so that you have:

```
dataTest.push({
    "userId": d["userId"], 
    "LevAvg": d["LevAvg"], 
    "Day": formattedDate, 
    "Lev": d["Lev"], 
    "Class": d["Class"], 
    "ActiveLocation": d["ActiveLocation"] 
});
```